# add custom style to datatables pagination

Tags: php, html, css, datatables

I have a page with datatables(server side) and I want to add my custom pagination style on it:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="pagination pagination-danger">
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" data-original-title="" title="">قبلی</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" data-original-title="" title="">1</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" data-original-title="" title="">2</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" data-original-title="" title="">3</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" data-original-title="" title="">بعدی</a></li>
</ul>
```

As you can see above my class name is `:page-link` and now I want to apply it on each datatables pagination items.

I searched for it anywhere, but I can't find a thorough solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want datatable pagination to use your custom classes, then use

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.classes.sPageButton = 'page-link';
```

before you initialize your datatable.

(From [Here](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/101733/#Comment_101733))

Answer (score 0):

This is a CSS question, no?

Ssee this link, you'll need to match it up to your classes:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_pagination.asp